# Crash when deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I have an assignment to create a PriorityQueue structure and  I'm having trouble with this piece of code. When I compile it on my compilator everything's fine, but I tried submitting it to ideone and I get the following error:

> "glibc detected *** ./prog: double free or corruption".

I was able to track the part that was giving me this error and I found out that what causes the crash is me trying to delete a pointer at the destructor of my class. The problem is that I don't know why I cant delete it. I don't know a lot about pointers but I thought that if I used new to allocate memory I had to delete it after using it and I think this is what I'm trying to do. Here is my code:

```
struct PriorityQueue
{
LinkedList queue; LinkNode *it,*node;
int sz;

PriorityQueue(){
    sz=0;
    queue.head=NULL;
    queue.tail=NULL;
    it = NULL;
    node=NULL;
}

~PriorityQueue(){

    if(node != NULL) //this is causing the error.
    delete [] node;


    if(it != NULL)
    delete [] it;
}


int size(){

    return sz;
}


void enqueue(int x){

    node = new LinkNode(x,NULL,NULL);

    if(sz==0){

        queue.insert_head(x);
        sz++;

    }

    else{

    if(x <= queue.head->value ){

        queue.insert_head(x);
        sz++;

    }

    else if( x>= queue.tail->value ){

        queue.insert_tail(x);
        sz++;

    }
    else{

        it = queue.head;


        for(int k=0;k<sz;k++){

                if( (x>= it->value)  && (x <= it->next->value) ){

                     node->next= it->next;
                     node->previous = it;

                     it->next->previous = node;
                     it->next = node;
                     sz++;
                     break;

                }

                    it=it->next;

        }

    }


    }

}

int dequeue_min(){

    int min = queue.remove_head();
    sz--;


    return min;
}

int dequeue_max(){

    int max= queue.remove_tail();
    sz--;

    return max;
}


};



int main()
{
PriorityQueue pq;
pq.enqueue(4);
pq.enqueue(2);
pq.enqueue(7);
pq.enqueue(-6);
pq.enqueue(0);
cout << pq.dequeue_min() << endl;   // debe imprimir -6
cout << pq.dequeue_min() << endl;   // debe imprimir 0
pq.enqueue(3);
cout << pq.dequeue_min() << endl;   // debe imprimir 2
cout << pq.dequeue_min() << endl;   // debe imprimir 3

return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using the wrong form of `delete` is UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` and `node` point to objects, not arrays.
You cannot use the array form of `delete[]` on them.

Answer (score 1):

Using delete[] will try to remove a pointer whose object is an array of some sort. There is another type of delete, that allows for the deletion of pointers to single objects. (Hint: it's pretty intuitive)

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting `it` and `node` using `delete []`. They are not arrays. You can only use `delete []` syntax on arrays or arrays of your objects. Remember the rule of thumb to use the similar delete and new commands for the same data types. If you have allocated memory by `new`, delete by `delete`. If you have allocated memory by `new []`, delete it  by `deete []`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `it` and `node` not only point to objects rather than arrays, as Slaks pointed out, it seems they also potentially point to the same thing. As a side note, you don't need to check for null before calling `delete[] p` or `delete p`: If the pointer `p` is null, this expression will have no effect.

It is unrelated to your question but please also note that your priority queue as `O(n)` (with `n` being the size) complexity. Typically, when implementing a priority queue you want to get `O(log(n))` complexity. The easiest strategy to implement such a priority queue is a [d-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap) which, conveniently, lives in an array and is actually easier to maintain than your linked list (I think, at least).